# ¿Por qué al cerrar sesión, en una vista específica, en la url no envía a la vista login y solo la sobrepone seguida del slash en Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js

Existen 2 vistas, una llamada **home** y otra llamada **parqueo**  cuando me encuentro en la vista home, exise un botón que ejecuta una funcion para redireccionarme a la visa `parqueo`a la cual le envió parámetros por la url:

Esta es la funcion que se ejecuta en la vista home:

```
parqueoSeleccionado(index) {
      console.log("SELECICONANDO PARQUEO");
      console.log(index);
      let obj_parqueo_seleccionado = {};
      obj_parqueo_seleccionado.id_zona_parqueo = this.id_zona_parqueo;
      obj_parqueo_seleccionado.id_parqueo = index;
      obj_parqueo_seleccionado.id_vehiculo = this.id_vehiculo;
      obj_parqueo_seleccionado.placa = this.placa;
      obj_parqueo_seleccionado.id_categoria = this.id_categoria;

      this.$router.replace({
        path: "parqueo/" + index,
        query: obj_parqueo_seleccionado
      }) //Aca mando los parámetros.
    }
```

Luego al encontrarme en la vista parqueo y cierro sesión:

```
cerrarSesion() {
      this.$router.replace({ query:{} });
      this.$router.replace({ params:{} });
      console.log("CERRAR SESION");
      console.log(this.$route)
      setTimeout(() => {
        firebase
        .auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {});
        this.$router.replace({ path: "login" });
        console.log(this.$route);
      }, 100);

    }
```

en la url me queda lo siguiente: `http://localhost:8081/#/parqueo/login`, cuando unicamente debería ser `http://localhost:8081/#/login`, pero que el problema me surge cuando envió parametros por la url, ya que al no mandar, no me da problemas.